# Initializing gradle doesn't finish in flutter app

Tags: android-studio, dart, android-gradle-plugin, flutter

I am making a flutter app on android studio and it was working but when I tried to run the app  initializing gradle started and I left him for a long time but it didn't finish I tried a solution from git hub site but it didn't work for me how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Please put errors and responses from the console. without this information, no one can understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same thing, but it turned out it was due to slow/dodgy internet. I experienced this on a public wifi, so when I tried launching my app again at home it worked.